# I'm trying to make a Tamagotchi and I'm having trouble updating it's current mood

Tags: python-3.x

```
hungry = 0
bored = 0
current_state = "Happy"
while True:
    print("Tamagotchi current state is:", current_state)
    action = input("")
    if action == "feed":
        hungry = hungry - 1
        bored = bored + 1
    elif action == "play":
        hungry = hungry + 1
        bored = bored - 1
    elif action == "ignore":
        hungry = hungry + 1
        bored = bored + 1    
    
    if current_state == 'HAPPY':
        if hungry >= 2:
            current_state = "HUNGRY"
        elif bored >= 2:
            current_state = "BORED"
        elif hungry >= 4:
            current_state = "SAD"
            if hungry < 0:
                hungry = 0
            if bored < 0:
                bored = 0
    
    if current_state == "HUNGRY":
        if hungry >= 4:
            current_state = "SAD"
        elif bored > hungry:
            current_state = "BORED"
        elif hungry < 2:
            current_state = "HAPPY"
            if hungry < 0:
                hungry = 0
            if bored < 0:
                bored = 0
    
    
    if current_state == "BORED":
        if bored >= 4:
            current_state = "SAD"
        elif hungry > bored:
            current_state = "HUNGRY"
        elif bored < 2:
            current_state = "Happy"
            if hungry < 0:
                hungry = 0
            if bored < 0:
                bored = 0
```

When I run the program and type in a action it still says happy even if I type feed in twice or play. Was planning on it changing it's mood based on a action a user types in. I have restraints where bored and hungry can never go below zero and if they do they get set back to zero. Also if the Tamagotchi becomes sad it should exit the while statement and print it's dead.

Answer (score 0):

might want to make your variables global. Pretty sure what's going on is when you call the (current_state) variable in your print statement, the actual variable never "updated" as intended, hence why it will always say it's happy. Hope that helps :)